# Checking list to see if strings exist in an argument, return values in a loop

Tags: python

Edit: I'd appreciate it more if someone could explain why this isn't working. I don't need anyone to do this for me, as I can go the long way about. I'd just like to understand why this isn't working. Thanks!

Edit #2: I'm aware that https:google.com isn't a url, but this was just to test the code.

I'm testing out different ways to check if url argument contains the strings 'http', 'www', or 'https' within the first 11 characters. Am I messing it up with the index? Or am I not understanding how 'in' and 'not in' work?

```
def check_url(url):
    first = ['www', 'http', 'https']
    for x in first:
        if x not in url[0:11]:
            return '[-] url fails'
        else:
           ...other stuff I need to check if it passes

hi = check_url('https:google.com')
print(hi)
```

The output says the url fails.

I have tried using 'in' as opposed to 'not in' (and of course rearranging wording to meet the requirements), but that didn't work either.

I'm aware that I could do multiple if statements to check each string individually, but that's a lot of code, and of course I want to make it as neat and readable as possible.

Comment: You return immediately after finding one string that isn't in your url string.

Comment: Oh I see. I was under the impression that the for statement would iterate through the entire list. 
Thank you!

Comment: No, `return` immediately breaks out of any loops and the function.

Comment: It will, but *you explicitly stop it by returning inside the loop*

Comment: Ahhh, okay, so I need to focus on the return statements?

Comment: Oh I got it! I'll use print instead; thank you guys so much!

Comment: a better way is to use `startswith()` statement in your case, and try not to use `return` inside the loop when you want all three elements to be checked.

Answer (score 0):

Your function breaks as soon as it has processed `return`. So the `for` loop no longer iterates. Move the `return` statement to the *end* of your function. For example:

```
def check_url(url):
    first = ['www', 'http', 'https']
    for x in first:
        if url.startswith(x):
            # ...other stuff I need to check if it passes
            # if successful:
            #     return 'url passes'
    return '[-] url fails'

hi = check_url('https:google.com')
```